# Change Header's container after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Bootstrap 3 Header. 
How do I make it so that when I scroll down, the container class changes to `.container-fluid`?
And with the scroll up to the end up, again became a `.container`.

My js knowledge is not very strong yet, I will be grateful for any help.

```js
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  /*height in pixels when the navbar becomes non opaque*/ 
    {
        $('.sticky-navbar').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.sticky-navbar').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

```css
#nav {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.65);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active>a {
    color: rgb(7, 105, 203);
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.25) solid;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #003366;
}
.navba-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
.sticky-navbar {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
    height: auto;
}
.sticky-navbar.sticky {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    height: auto;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-right {
    float: right!important;
    padding: 30px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 18.5px 16px;
    color: #474747;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:before {
content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #ffa804;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a.active {
    color: #bb2a2d;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav-alt>li>a {
    color: #000;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
}
ul.custom-pull {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top sticky-navbar">
        <div class="header-top">
           <div class="container text-right">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-warning">
                    Open Account
                </a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline">
                    Login
                </a>
                    <div class="chat_wrapper">
                        <a href=""></a>
                    </div><!-- chat-wrapper -->
           </div><!-- header-top .container -->
       </div><!-- header-top -->
       
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logo</a><!-- !logo! -->
            </div><!-- navbar header -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMain">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right custom-pull">
                    <li><a href="#l">Advantage</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Software</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Partner</a>
                </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul><!-- !main-menu! -->
            </div><!-- collapse -->
      </div><!-- navbar container -->
    </div><!-- navbar -->
    
    <body>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec porttitor ullamcorper mauris, in scelerisque lorem feugiat eu. Etiam eget magna vel nibh placerat maximus quis id ligula. Morbi id congue urna. Donec vel accumsan lorem, eget sagittis purus. Donec in condimentum quam, ut blandit mi. Duis maximus fermentum diam. Nulla scelerisque nec tellus at sodales. Etiam euismod turpis vitae turpis porttitor, vitae malesuada libero fringilla. Mauris faucibus nisi et dolor lobortis volutpat.

Etiam et neque ultrices, faucibus risus non, eleifend neque. Phasellus feugiat luctus imperdiet. Morbi egestas luctus libero, a auctor nisi imperdiet nec. Vivamus id nisl finibus, imperdiet tellus vitae, molestie tellus. Mauris gravida arcu non metus rutrum ultrices. Sed eu egestas dolor. Sed blandit congue ornare. Cras tristique, libero non ultrices auctor, erat lectus interdum ipsum, at rhoncus justo urna non nunc.

Donec a aliquet leo. Morbi ante magna, scelerisque quis consequat porttitor, aliquam eu neque. Ut eu malesuada magna. Aliquam lobortis mi mollis turpis ornare tempor. Pellentesque et accumsan turpis. Praesent egestas lacinia arcu, ut pretium metus facilisis sit amet. Cras pharetra non tellus id sagittis.

Mauris feugiat diam a lacinia vulputate. Suspendisse potenti. In bibendum, tortor et dictum ornare, velit nulla mattis erat, ut laoreet mi eros eu augue. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed nibh mattis, malesuada est non, hendrerit purus. Nullam ac dui urna. Maecenas nec dui convallis dui luctus auctor id ac sem. Duis aliquam lorem orci, non pellentesque neque facilisis feugiat. Cras ornare, nulla quis gravida mattis, est magna venenatis diam, ac sagittis mauris nunc ac quam. Proin sodales vestibulum accumsan. Mauris tellus turpis, blandit id consectetur at, pulvinar a ipsum. Aenean iaculis tempor sem vitae finibus. Duis vel sem lorem. Phasellus condimentum odio id nunc placerat, id bibendum felis aliquet. Phasellus rutrum lectus ultrices vestibulum cursus. Mauris in ligula velit.

Mauris feugiat diam a lacinia vulputate. Suspendisse potenti. In bibendum, tortor et dictum ornare, velit nulla mattis erat, ut laoreet mi eros eu augue. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed nibh mattis, malesuada est non, hendrerit purus. Nullam ac dui urna. Maecenas nec dui convallis dui luctus auctor id ac sem. Duis aliquam lorem orci, non pellentesque neque facilisis feugiat. Cras ornare, nulla quis gravida mattis, est magna venenatis diam, ac sagittis mauris nunc ac quam. Proin sodales vestibulum accumsan. Mauris tellus turpis, blandit id consectetur at, pulvinar a ipsum. Aenean iaculis tempor sem vitae finibus. Duis vel sem lorem. Phasellus condimentum odio id nunc placerat, id bibendum felis aliquet. Phasellus rutrum lectus ultrices vestibulum cursus. Mauris in ligula velit.

Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec ut mauris ut enim posuere accumsan et non mi. Vivamus volutpat porttitor sagittis. Maecenas eget urna elit. Pellentesque sit amet faucibus est. Praesent a lorem id felis ullamcorper hendrerit. Maecenas egestas mi felis, id condimentum ante malesuada ut. Nunc quis quam eget urna blandit blandit. Sed facilisis, eros ac eleifend blandit, velit mauris euismod arcu, et imperdiet magna libero nec nibh. Suspendisse faucibus libero suscipit, sollicitudin metus accumsan, porttitor diam. Donec non neque nisl. Phasellus tempus commodo ante, quis auctor mi.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  /*height in pixels when the navbar becomes non opaque*/ 
    {
        $('.sticky-navbar').addClass('sticky');
        $('.navbar .container').addClass('container-fluid', 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $('.navbar .container').removeClass('container', 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
    } else {
        $('.sticky-navbar').removeClass('sticky');
        $('.navbar .container-fluid').addClass('container', 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $('.navbar .container-fluid').removeClass('container-fluid', 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
    }
});
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  /*height in pixels when the navbar becomes non opaque*/ 
    {
        $('.sticky-navbar').addClass('sticky');
        $('.navbar .container').addClass('container-fluid', 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $('.navbar .container').removeClass('container', 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
    } else {
        $('.sticky-navbar').removeClass('sticky');
        $('.navbar .container-fluid').addClass('container', 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $('.navbar .container-fluid').removeClass('container-fluid', 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
    }
});
```

```css
#nav {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.65);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active>a {
    color: rgb(7, 105, 203);
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.25) solid;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #003366;
}
.navba-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
.sticky-navbar {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
    height: auto;
}
.sticky-navbar.sticky {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    height: auto;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-right {
    float: right!important;
    padding: 30px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 18.5px 16px;
    color: #474747;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:before {
content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #ffa804;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover:before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a.active {
    color: #bb2a2d;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav-alt>li>a {
    color: #000;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
}
ul.custom-pull {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"/>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top sticky-navbar">
        <div class="header-top">
           <div class="container text-right">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-warning">
                    Open Account
                </a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline">
                    Login
                </a>
                    <div class="chat_wrapper">
                        <a href=""></a>
                    </div><!-- chat-wrapper -->
           </div><!-- header-top .container -->
       </div><!-- header-top -->
       
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logo</a><!-- !logo! -->
            </div><!-- navbar header -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMain">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right custom-pull">
                    <li><a href="#l">Advantage</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Software</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Partner</a>
                </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul><!-- !main-menu! -->
            </div><!-- collapse -->
      </div><!-- navbar container -->
    </div><!-- navbar -->
    
    <body>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec porttitor ullamcorper mauris, in scelerisque lorem feugiat eu. Etiam eget magna vel nibh placerat maximus quis id ligula. Morbi id congue urna. Donec vel accumsan lorem, eget sagittis purus. Donec in condimentum quam, ut blandit mi. Duis maximus fermentum diam. Nulla scelerisque nec tellus at sodales. Etiam euismod turpis vitae turpis porttitor, vitae malesuada libero fringilla. Mauris faucibus nisi et dolor lobortis volutpat.

Etiam et neque ultrices, faucibus risus non, eleifend neque. Phasellus feugiat luctus imperdiet. Morbi egestas luctus libero, a auctor nisi imperdiet nec. Vivamus id nisl finibus, imperdiet tellus vitae, molestie tellus. Mauris gravida arcu non metus rutrum ultrices. Sed eu egestas dolor. Sed blandit congue ornare. Cras tristique, libero non ultrices auctor, erat lectus interdum ipsum, at rhoncus justo urna non nunc.

Donec a aliquet leo. Morbi ante magna, scelerisque quis consequat porttitor, aliquam eu neque. Ut eu malesuada magna. Aliquam lobortis mi mollis turpis ornare tempor. Pellentesque et accumsan turpis. Praesent egestas lacinia arcu, ut pretium metus facilisis sit amet. Cras pharetra non tellus id sagittis.

Mauris feugiat diam a lacinia vulputate. Suspendisse potenti. In bibendum, tortor et dictum ornare, velit nulla mattis erat, ut laoreet mi eros eu augue. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed nibh mattis, malesuada est non, hendrerit purus. Nullam ac dui urna. Maecenas nec dui convallis dui luctus auctor id ac sem. Duis aliquam lorem orci, non pellentesque neque facilisis feugiat. Cras ornare, nulla quis gravida mattis, est magna venenatis diam, ac sagittis mauris nunc ac quam. Proin sodales vestibulum accumsan. Mauris tellus turpis, blandit id consectetur at, pulvinar a ipsum. Aenean iaculis tempor sem vitae finibus. Duis vel sem lorem. Phasellus condimentum odio id nunc placerat, id bibendum felis aliquet. Phasellus rutrum lectus ultrices vestibulum cursus. Mauris in ligula velit.

Mauris feugiat diam a lacinia vulputate. Suspendisse potenti. In bibendum, tortor et dictum ornare, velit nulla mattis erat, ut laoreet mi eros eu augue. Nulla facilisi. Integer sed nibh mattis, malesuada est non, hendrerit purus. Nullam ac dui urna. Maecenas nec dui convallis dui luctus auctor id ac sem. Duis aliquam lorem orci, non pellentesque neque facilisis feugiat. Cras ornare, nulla quis gravida mattis, est magna venenatis diam, ac sagittis mauris nunc ac quam. Proin sodales vestibulum accumsan. Mauris tellus turpis, blandit id consectetur at, pulvinar a ipsum. Aenean iaculis tempor sem vitae finibus. Duis vel sem lorem. Phasellus condimentum odio id nunc placerat, id bibendum felis aliquet. Phasellus rutrum lectus ultrices vestibulum cursus. Mauris in ligula velit.

Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec ut mauris ut enim posuere accumsan et non mi. Vivamus volutpat porttitor sagittis. Maecenas eget urna elit. Pellentesque sit amet faucibus est. Praesent a lorem id felis ullamcorper hendrerit. Maecenas egestas mi felis, id condimentum ante malesuada ut. Nunc quis quam eget urna blandit blandit. Sed facilisis, eros ac eleifend blandit, velit mauris euismod arcu, et imperdiet magna libero nec nibh. Suspendisse faucibus libero suscipit, sollicitudin metus accumsan, porttitor diam. Donec non neque nisl. Phasellus tempus commodo ante, quis auctor mi.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thank you. But this script changed the container to me everywhere, not only in the header.
By the way, could you, please, let me know if you can help me how to add a SlideOutLeft animation to the container elements after scroll?

Comment: Thanks Gattbha! This solution works great! Could you, please, also help me with the following ? (don't want to open a new thread for this simple question). I integrated animate.css for my website. How can I make that when the scroll when the containers are changed the animation starts? (For example .slideOutLeft)

Comment: you need to use scrollspy or wowjs or any animation scroll plugin.

Comment: I did not correctly ask the question. How can I make the classes change smoothly? To be able to see how the container COMES TO the left and right. I tried to use transition-duration: 1s, but it does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169574/discussion-between-gattbha-and-morgari).

Comment: Everything works great!
Thank you so much for your help, friend!

Comment: @Morgari Welcome Mate

Answer (score 1):

As you did:

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) 
    {
        $('.header-top .container').addClass('container-fluid');
        $('.header-top .container').removeClass('container');
        $('.sticky-navbar').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.header-top .container-fluid').addClass('container');
        $('.header-top .container-fluid').removeClass('container-fluid');
        $('.sticky-navbar').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

**Explain:** 
if you want to **add** class you have to use `addClass` function
So you have to say for what you want to add the class and then in `addClass` function write the class name
In your case you want to change  the class so you need to use `removeClass` function
It means that you find the tag by his current `class` **add** the other `class` and then **remove** the current